# How can I interact with the Github API using Perl6?

Tags: http, github, raku, rakudo

I want to use the Github API in a script and I want to use it as an experience to get better using Perl6. However, I cannot even get a simple proof of concept to work.

Through some testing I realized that Github [requires](https://developer.github.com/v3/#user-agent-required) that you supply a valid user agent so I turned to [HTTP::UserAgent](https://github.com/sergot/http-useragent). No matter what I try, I get the following error:

```
Internal Error: 'server returned no data'
  in block  at /Applications/Rakudo/share/perl6/site/sources/FD28A8E22DFE16B70B757D9981C7B6C25543060C (HTTP::UserAgent) line 259
  in any  at /Applications/Rakudo/share/perl6/site/precomp/F91BAB44DF15C5C298C627DD5E0F9D819ED79939.1517344679.60204/FD/FD28A8E22DFE16B70B757D9981C7B6C25543060C line 1
  in method new at /Applications/Rakudo/share/perl6/site/sources/DDDD4497B34FC81BC1F5FF467999BC4DA2FA1CEB (HTTP::Response) line 25
  in method get-response at /Applications/Rakudo/share/perl6/site/sources/FD28A8E22DFE16B70B757D9981C7B6C25543060C (HTTP::UserAgent) line 291
  in method request at /Applications/Rakudo/share/perl6/site/sources/FD28A8E22DFE16B70B757D9981C7B6C25543060C (HTTP::UserAgent) line 159
  in method get at /Applications/Rakudo/share/perl6/site/sources/FD28A8E22DFE16B70B757D9981C7B6C25543060C (HTTP::UserAgent) line 102
  in method get at /Applications/Rakudo/share/perl6/site/sources/FD28A8E22DFE16B70B757D9981C7B6C25543060C (HTTP::UserAgent) line 105
  in block <unit> at reporter.pl6 line 12
```

There is even [an example](https://github.com/sergot/http-useragent/blob/master/examples/ex_readme.p6) in the the repo that doesn't seem to work for me.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl6
use v6;
use HTTP::UserAgent;

my $ua = HTTP::UserAgent.new;
$ua.timeout = 1;

my $response = $ua.get('https://github.com');

if $response.is-success {
    say $response.content;
} else {
    die $response.status-line;
}
```

Any tips on how to connect to Github via Perl 6? I really love many aspects of the language but this type of thing is discouraging.

EDIT: I went on #perl6 irc and no one was able to reproduce this on other OSes. I got it to work on Debian. The issue seems to be with OS X

Comment: That example seems to be using homepage instead of an API endpoint.

What's the program that produces the error you pasted? Our IRC bot that [uses HTTP::UserAgent](https://github.com/perl6/geth/blob/c150dd327d3414862898b24d091811c2d9cdb5a2/lib/Geth/GitHub/Hooks/Preprocessor.pm6#L7) works fine. There's also [WebService::GitHub](https://modules.perl6.org/repo/WebService::GitHub) in ecosystem.

Comment: I tried to use an API endpoint at first: `https://api.github.com/users/:username/events` and got the same error.

I'll look into the ecosystem module you posted -- but it's still odd that UserAgent doesn't seem to work.

Comment: FWIW, [another user verified](https://irclog.perlgeek.de/perl6/2018-04-20#i_16072080) that it works on OSX for them. The one thing you could try is [build the latest compiler from source](https://gist.github.com/zoffixznet/7f2b3ad3d3a6665baf84107c36283cb0) to see if it's some recent bug that got fixed. Though I don't particularly remember anything obvious getting in since 2018.01 as far as fixes go.

Comment: Thanks I appreciate that you had someone test this on OS X. It's possible that it's my openssl version that's out of date. I'll update this post when I find out.

Answer (score 2):

Although in alpha stage, [`WebServices::GitHub`](https://github.com/fayland/perl6-WebService-GitHub) is perfectly serviceable. You can use it to download user information, or you can use [my fork](https://github.com/fayland/perl6-WebService-GitHub) if you want to interact with issues. [This program](https://github.com/JJ/TPF-Grant/blob/master/utils/download_some_issues.p6), for instance, is used to download some issues from a particular repo.